# When can percentile ranks be used in statistical analyses?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

Given that percentile ranks are ordinal rather than metric, which statistical analyses would be appropriate to run with PRs? I understand some options include converting PRs to standardized scores (eg z scores) to solve this issue, but I am interested to learn and justify the limitations of using PRs in (parametric) statistical analysis and be able to explain this clearly.

Here is some additional and clarifying information: 
I have a dataset that includes student math scores (PRs and standardized scores) from multiple time points on the same measure (not alternate forms). I want to determine (1) if students made significant improvement based on change from time 1 (e.g., PR:30) to time 2 (e.g., PR:44) based on PRs or justify why PRs can't be used if that's the case.

Comment: Since this question has a very large number of possible (correct) answers, it may be too broad for our format.

Comment: There was [nice paper](https://econresearch.uchicago.edu/sites/econresearch.uchicago.edu/files/Nielsen.pdf) about this topic by an economist named Eric Nielsen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One limitation on PRs is that they have poor differential privacy.

One consequence of this is that if you make a model using PRs and then test it with a held out test set, you have significantly depleted the test set's value. If you iterate this you can overfit the test set. A statistic that is a mean of some values has less potential for overfitting by steering. Se Dwork's publications for details.